# Why NSMutableArray doesn't save the data one the view has changed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have a tableviewcontroller (Stops) that shows a list of stops (stopsArray), where the user can mark a specific Stop like his Favourite. After touching an UIImage, the stop is saved on the NSMutableArray (myStopsMArray). And until here everything is ok. But at the moment when I leave that viewcontroller I lose all the data of the NSMutableArray. Here is my code:

Stops.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface Stops : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *stopsTable;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *stopsArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myStopsMArray;

@end
```

Stops.m:

```
#import "Stops.h"
#import "Stop.h"
#import "MyStops.h"
#import "Global.h"

@interface Stops ()

@end

 @implementation Stops

@synthesize stopsArray, myStopsMArray, stopsTable;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!self.myStopsMArray) {
        self.myStopsMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

}


- (void) addToFavourites:(id)sender {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;

    NSInteger tag = gesture.view.tag;

    NSIndexPath *tagIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:tag inSection:0];

     UITableViewCell *cell = [stopsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:tagIndex];

     if ([cell.imageView.image isEqual: [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_filled_white.png"]]) {
        // Add Stop to favourites

        [self.myStopsMArray addObject:[stopsArray objectAtIndex:tag]];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_filled_yellow.png"];

    } else {
    // Delete Stops from favourites

        [self.myStopsMArray removeObject:[stopsArray objectAtIndex:tag]];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_filled_white.png"];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.myStopsMArray forKey:@"myStopsMArray"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];


    NSArray *savedData = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"myStopsMArray"];

    NSLog(@"%@", savedData);

}

@end
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: are you loading array values from NSUserDefaults when open this view again?

Comment: yes, but anyway if I simply do 'NSLog(@"%@", self.myStopsMArray);' I have nothing. What can be the cause?

Comment: When you leave the view controller, the array has already been deallocated. If you want persistent data, you need to save the contents of the array elsewhere.

Comment: Right. I'm stupid. The error was doing exactly that when comparing to set the star. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if someone is at the same place as me, this is the magic line –already corrected–:

Stops.m:

```
if ([savedData containsObject: [stopsArray objectAtIndex:index]]) {
    ...
}
```

Don't forget declare NSUserDefaults previously too:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *savedData = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"myStopsMArray"];
```